# How do you group a dataframe based on a column with string values?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, group-by

I am having some trouble using `groupby` to group a `df` based on the numeric value in a string. The regular expression `(\w+)_\w+` should match to the digit in the string with which I wish to make a group, however I am unsure how to implement this with `groupby`.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['ab_c_1.0','ab_c_1.1','ab_c_12.0','ab_c_12.1','ab_c_123.0','ab_c_123.1']})
```

Desired groupings:

```
             x
0     ab_c_1.0
1     ab_c_1.1

2    ab_c_12.0
3    ab_c_12.1

4   ab_c_123.0
5   ab_c_123.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options would be to [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the three parts then ask for their [`ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ngroup.html) :

```
grp = df["x"].str.extract(r"(\D+)_(\d+)\.(\d+)").groupby([0,1]).ngroup().add(1)

#[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Another variant with [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) & [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)  :

```
grp = (~df["x"].str.split(".").str[0].duplicated()).cumsum()

#[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

If you need to assign the group numbers to a separate/new column, use `df["group"] = grp`.

Output :

```
for _, g in df.groupby(grp):
    print(g)
          x
0  ab_c_1.0
1  ab_c_1.1
           x
2  ab_c_12.0
3  ab_c_12.1
            x
4  ab_c_123.0
5  ab_c_123.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `.str.split()`:

```py
for _, g in df.groupby(df['x'].str.split('.').str[0]):
    print(g)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
          x
0  ab_c_1.0
1  ab_c_1.1

           x
2  ab_c_12.0
3  ab_c_12.1

            x
4  ab_c_123.0
5  ab_c_123.1
```